# Echo selected when a variable is equal to another in a select built by PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, selected

Hy Guys,
I need a little help with this script:
I want to echo selected in a PHP and MySQL built selector.
This is my actual code

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','*****','thisisapassword','****');
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
           die('Errore : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }


      // CREATE QUERY STRING
    $sql = "SELECT sede_ID, provincia, indirizzo FROM sedi ORDER BY sede_ID, provincia";
      // RUN QUERY
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
      /**
       * TEST FOR QUERY SUCCESS HERE, POSSIBLY TRIGGER_ERROR()
       */
      // START THE SELECT CONTROL
    $out = '<select name="sede" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="sede">' . PHP_EOL;
      // THE CURRENT STATE IS KEPT HERE
    $old = '?';
      // THE INITIAL OPTGROUP STATUS IS KEPT HERE
    $grp = FALSE;
      // USE AN ITERATOR TO RETRIEVE THE ROWS OF THE RESULTS SET
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
      // IF THIS IS A ROW WITH A NEW STATE?
      if ($row->provincia != $old)
      {
        // IF THERE IS AN EXISTING OPT-GROUP
        if ($grp)
          {
        // TIE OFF THE OLD OPT-GROUP
        $out .= '</optgroup>' . PHP_EOL;
          }
          // ADD THE OPT-GROUP FOR THE NEW STATE
          $out .= '<optgroup label="' . $row->provincia . '">' . PHP_EOL;
          $out .= '<option value="' . $row->sede_ID . '">' . $row->indirizzo . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
          // CHANGE STATES
          $old = $row->provincia;
          $grp = TRUE;
        }
      // IF THIS IS ANOTHER CITY IN THE SAME STATE
      else
      {
        // JUST ADD THE CITY OPTION
        $out .= '<option value="' . $row->sede_ID . '">' . $row->indirizzo . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
      }
    }
    // AT THE END OF THE RESULTS SET, TIE OFF THE OPT-GROUP AND THE SELECT CONTROL
    $out .= '</optgroup>' . PHP_EOL;
    $out .= '</select>' . PHP_EOL;
      ?>
      <?php echo $out;  ?>
```

The problem is when i try to add the code to select the db defined option.
The variable for the database option option to be selected is $sede, I tried to make a function that echo selected if $sede is equal (==) to row->sede_ID but it doesn't work.
Can anyone please help me with this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Just a style point, ALL CAPS COMMENTS are hard to read, and some blank lines may also help

Comment: So am I right in saying that you have a $sede variable (generated elsewhere in your PHP code)? And that basically when $row->sede == $sede, you want to echo " selected='selected'"; within the <option> tag?

Comment: Yes, when $row->sede_ID == $sede i want to echo selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, include an extra variable within your  tag. If the values don't match you leave this as an empty string, otherwise include the "selected" attribute

(Within your loop)

```
// Show an option for the city
$out .= "<option value='{$row->sede_ID}'>{$row->indirizzo}</option>" . PHP_EOL;
```

becomes

```
// Decide whether to select the current city as the selected value
if ( $sede == $row->sede_ID)
{
    // Select this city
    $selectedText = "selected='selected'";
}
else
{
    // Don't select this city
    $selectedText = "";
}

// Show an option for the city
$out .= "<option value='{$row->sede_ID}' $selectedText>{$row->indirizzo}</option>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Note that for clarity, I've removed your text concatenations and just included the variables within the string: this is usually considered acceptable within PHP: the curly braces {} prevent strange things happening with $object->field variables

If the $row->sede_id == $sede, it outputs

```
<option value='123' selected='selected'>yourtext</option>
```

Otherwise it outputs

```
<option value='123'>yourtext</option>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.
Just one thing? Why you use double quotes instead of concatenations? And can i use NULL instead of empty for $selectedText?
Thanks Again

Comment: You could use null: with strings I prefer to use an empty string "" as it can be clearer and more consistent both within PHP and with other languages. And I use "" instead of '' because it allows you to then use '' for html key='value' pairs, and include $variables or $array['key'] within the quotes without worrying about it. I'm not sure if everyone agrees, but I feel that this way is easier to read.

Comment: Note that a concatenation is where you do $var = "text " . $variable . " text"; instead of $var = "text $variable text"; and has nothing to do with the type of quote

Comment: Thanks again, I always use concatenation with single quotes because an expert programmer said me that it was faster than double quotes with or without concatenation.

Comment: It is... marginally. We're talking tiny fractions of seconds, though, and you almost certainly have lots of much worse sub-optimal code lying around in any normal application. Unless you're running Facebook, you almost certainly don't care.